# Plotting distribution of differences in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset with numbers indicating daily difference in some measure.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/diff.csv

I would like to create a plot of the distribution of the differences with special emphasis on the rare large changes.

I tried plotting each column using the hist() function but it doesn't really provide a detailed picture of the data.

For example plotting the first column of the dataset produces the following plot:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/Rplot.pdf

My problem is that this gives very little detail to the infrequent large deviations.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Also any suggestions on how to summarize this data in a table? For example besides showing the min, max and mean values, would you look at quantiles? Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for. One way to make this question more specific would be to post some plots that you've made, and explain what it is that you don't like about them.

Comment: +1 simply because you provided data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [boxplots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) to visualize the distribution of the data:

```
sdiff <- read.csv("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/diff.csv")

boxplot(sdiff[,-1])
```

Outliers are printed as circles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I back @Sven's suggestion for identifying outliers, but you can get more refinement in your histograms by specifying a denser set of breakpoints than what `hist` chooses by default.

```
d <- read.csv('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/diff.csv', header=TRUE, row.names=1)
with(d, hist(a, breaks=seq(min(a), max(a), length.out=100)))
```

[image]

Comment: any way of drawing the histogram with all the 10 columns on the same as in the boxplot example?

Answer (score 1):

[Violin plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot) could be useful:

```
df <- read.csv('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/diff.csv')
library(vioplot)
with(df,vioplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j))
```

[image: violin plots]

I would use a boxplot on transformed data, e.g.:

```
boxplot(df[,-1]/sqrt(abs(df[,-1])))
```

[image: boxplot (data transformed)]

Obviously a histogram would also look better after transformation.